# Reused UITableViewCells duplicating in some instances

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview and each cell contains another tableview for horizontal scrolling.  The main tableview is only 6 Cells high, so initially I wasn't reusing cells, though the vertical scrolling was choppy so I decided to reuse cells.  Within the vertical tableview there are 3 different types of horizontal cells.  2 types are working just fine.  1 type is duplicating.  I show a diagram here to hopefully explain this better:

```
Vertical TableView

Row 0 Cell type A
Row 1 Cell type B
Row 2 Cell type C
Row 3 Cell type C
Row 4 Cell type C
Row 5 Cell type B
Row 6 Cell type C
```

They are all displaying correctly except for some reason the data displayed in Row 6 is the same as the data displayed in Row 2.  There are clearly other rows that are Type C, but only 2-6 are duplicated.  I have checked the data array, and the correct data is being passed to that row.  Additionally when I scroll row 6, and go up to row 2, it is also scrolled to the same index.  When I turn off reusing cells, this problem goes away, but then scrolling isn't smooth.  Here is the tableview code for the troubled cell type.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HorizontalCell";
  HorizontalTableCell *cell = (HorizontalTableCell *)[self.homeTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       if (cell == nil)
        {
           cell = [[HorizontalTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.homeTable.frame.size.width, self.homeTable.frame.size.height)];

                    // Configure cell
                    UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"verticalCell-back.png"];
                    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.frame];
                    [bgView setImage:bgImage];
                    cell.backgroundView = bgView;

                    // Set up the title label
                    UILabel * titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
                    titleLabel.tag = TITLE_LABEL_TAG;
                    titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
                    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
                    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);

                    // Set up the value label
                    UILabel * titleValueLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
                    titleValueLabel.tag = TITLE_VALUE_LABEL_TAG;
                    titleValueLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
                    titleValueLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    titleValueLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    titleValueLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    titleValueLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);

                    [cell addSubview:titleValueLabel];
                    [cell addSubview:titleLabel];

                    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                }

                cell.data = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
                cell.horizontalTableView.scrollsToTop = NO;

                for (int i = 0; i < [[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] count]; i++ ) {
                    PosterData *poster = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:i];
                    NSLog(@"Row Number %u Data %@", indexPath.section, poster.name);
                }

                //Set up the title label
                NSArray *labelTextArray =  [[titlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] componentsSeparatedByString:@"**"];
                CGSize expectedLabelSize = [[labelTextArray objectAtIndex:0] sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]
                                                                        constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 15)
                                                                            lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];

                // Get the labels
                UILabel * titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:TITLE_LABEL_TAG];
                UILabel * titleValueLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:TITLE_VALUE_LABEL_TAG];

                titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(8, 13, expectedLabelSize.width + 2, 15);
                titleValueLabel.frame = CGRectMake(expectedLabelSize.width + 8, 13, 150, 15);

                titleLabel.text = [labelTextArray objectAtIndex:0];
                NSLog(@"Label Text Array %@", labelTextArray);
                if ([labelTextArray count] > 1) {
                    titleValueLabel.text = [labelTextArray objectAtIndex:1];
                }
                else titleValueLabel.text = @"";

                return cell;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as how nobody commented, I solved the problem. Thought I would share the answer.  I had not implemented `-(void) prepareForReuse` in my cells.  I just reload the horizontal tableView in that method, solved my problem